# JaxRS Exception mapper not found

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, web.xml

I have a `@Provider` annotated exception mapper, but Jersey isn't loading or registering it.

In my `web.xml` (trimmed down):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.my.company;
            com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json;
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

the mapper:

```
package com.my.company.some.package;

@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

I have `@Path` annotated API classes in the `com.my.company.other.package` package, those are found correctly and I can access them without problems. None of the `@Provider` annotated mappers are found.

If I put a log message in the mapper constructor and/or the `toResponse` method, those aren't displayed either. I'm forced to conclude that Jersey just can't find or decides not to load the classes. How do I get this to work?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've provided. Maybe something you are not providing. Not sure what it could be.  Can you provided a small github project that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The provider packages attribute in jersey is not recursive.  It scans those packages only, not packages starting with that name.

Comment: The recursive behavior is actually dependent on the property [`jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_PACKAGES), which is true by default

Comment: I checked, and the property is not in my `web.xml`, so I assume it will default to true. This is backed up by the fact that the `@Path` annotated classes in subpackages are loaded correctly.

Comment: and just wondering, did you try adding the package name explicitly?